# Как правильно объявлять itoa в Visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, c++, visual-studio-2012

При запуске приложения вылетает ошибка:

> The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _itoa. см. объявление "itoa"....

Как правильно объявлять `itoa`? Библиотека `<stdlib.h>` подключена.

Comment: Если хотите менять код, то просто замените на `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Доброго времени суток! 
Я так понимаю используется MS Visual Studio.
Если так, то на мой взгляд у Вас есть 2 пути:

первый - снизить уровень жесткости проверки синтаксиса и используемых функций, что не рекомендуется;

второй - использовать более безопасные по мнению Microsoft функции: (_itoa_s, _i64toa_s, _ui64toa_s, _itow_s, и проч.)

Ссылки:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235327%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0we9x30h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175759%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Да, и еще если все таки будете использовать именно itoa, (часто бывает что иного выхода нет, особенно если имеете дело со старыми исходниками), и не хотите чтобы валились предупреждения, то можно в опциях компилятора установить predefined defines следующего вида:

_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE

Answer (score 2):

`_itoa` не нужно объявлять, она уже объявлена в `<stdlib.h>`

Просто подключить `<stdlib.h>` и использовать.

Comment: @fogbit, я её и использую, а компилятор выдаёт ошибку

Comment: скорее нужно подключать `<cstdlid>`, чем `<stdlib.h>`

в остальном уже сказали, что мелкомягкие принуждают использовать их расширения в CRT.

Comment: это разве ошибка? по-моему предупреждение

Comment: Что именно ошибка или предупреждение?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше itoa не использовать вообще, делать лучше так:

include <stream>
…
sstream ss;
ss < `число которое нужно сконвертить` <std::endl;
`переменная` = ss.str();

Прошу не пинать за возможные ошибки, т.к. писал по помяти.

Comment: @Airhand, во первых, `itoa`

    void* itoa(int input, char *buffer, int radix)

позволяет задать систему счисления, отличную от десятичной,

а во вторых, если уж ограничиваться десятичной, то меня всегда удивляет подход - "*зачем просто, если можно сложно*".

Согласитесь, что `sprintf()` проще (и на порядок эффективнее) возни со `sstream`.

Comment: Чтобы указать систему счисления при использовании стандартнык потоков ввода-вывода, используйте `std::setbase`. 
`sprintf` считается небезопасной функцией и стоит воздержаться от её использования в C++ коде.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю как добавлять коменты. Во первых, аргумент itoa не всегда int, а это неявное преобразование со всеми вытекающими (скорость, точность). Во-вторых второй аргумент itoa – буфер неизвестной длины. Если задать очень большую длину – будет перерасход памяти, а если сильно маленький – результат может не поместиться. И где простота ?

Comment: Точность? Для целых чисел это что-то непонятное. Скорость? Сколько миллионов чисел Вам нужно преобразовать? Большая длина -- есть максимальное (а лучше минимально, там ещё знак минус) целое. +1 на заключительный ноль. Больше не надо.

Comment: На некоторых системах longint равен 4 байта, на тех же системах int – 2 байта, в итоге может потеряться 2 байта при преобразовании, кроме того, преобразование которое выполняется несколько тысяч раз (в реальных программах может и больше) занимает значительное время. Не забываем про буфер неизвестной длины.

P.S. Я разобрался как добавлять комментарии.

Comment: Для long int используется (использовалась) функция ltoa

Comment: Я знаю, что есть ltoa, но компилятор автоматически сконвертит число и потеряются 2 байта и компилятор ничего не скажет об ошибке. Такие ошибки в коде, который составляет тысячи строк, очень тяжело искать.

Comment: @Airhand Боюсь, это возрастное. Рецепт один -- такие инструменты нафиг, пользуйтесь теми, где данная проблема (автоматическое приведение типа) отсутствует, как класс. Из visual studio, если не трогать ооп-заморочек, наиболее близок к требуемому F#